# Finite group acting freely on a smooth manifold (De Rham cohomology)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms, group-actions, de-rham-cohomology

I have a finite group $G$ acting freely on a manifold and $\pi:M\to M/G$ is the covering map. I need to show that the induced (pullback) map $\pi^*:H^*(M/G)\to H^*(M)$ is injective, where $H^*(M)=\oplus_{k=0}^n H^k(M).$

I have some questions. The first one is how to justify that if $\dim M=n$ then $\dim M/G=n$ (is that always true?)

In such a case, the induced map $\pi^*:H^0(M/G)\oplus\cdots\oplus H^n(M/G)\to H^0(M)\oplus\cdots\oplus H^n(M)$ would be defined as 
$$\pi^*(a_0+\ldots+a_n)=\pi_0^*(a_0)+\ldots+\pi_n^*(a_n),$$
where $\pi_k^*:H^k(M/G)\to H^k(M)$ is the pullback of a class of $k-$forms in $H^k(M/G)$ to $H^k(M).$

Now I try to prove injectivity. If I assume that $$\pi^*(a_0+\ldots+a_n)=\pi^*(b_0+\ldots+b_n),$$
then
$$\pi_0^*(a_0)+\ldots+\pi_n^*(a_n)=\pi_0^*(b_0)+\ldots+\pi_n^*(b_n)\in H^*(M).$$
By uniqueness in the direct sum, we have $\pi_j^*(a_j)=\pi_j^*(b_j)$ for all $j=0,1,\ldots,n.$
This means that, for every $j,$ there exists $\gamma_j\in\Omega^{j-1}(M/G)$ such that $\pi_j^*(a_j)=\pi_j^*(b_j)+d\gamma_j.$ 
Since $\pi_j^*$ is a linear map, then $\pi_j^*(a_j-b_j)=d\gamma_j.$

This implies that $d(\pi_j^*(a_j-b_j))=d(d\gamma_j))=0$ and using the fact that derivative and pullback commute, then $\pi_j^*(da_j-db_j)=0,$ so $da_j-db_j\in\ker\pi_j^*.$

I don't know how to proceed because nothing ensures that $\pi_j^*$ is an injective map.

Corrections and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: 1. You don't seem to have ever used the fact that $\pi$ is a covering map. 2. For a finite group acting freely on a manifold of dimension $n$, the dimension of the quotient is indeed $n$. (You should prove this. Hint: pick a coordinate neighborhood $U$ of $p$ so small that $U \cap gU = \emptyset$ for all $g \ in G$. How do you know such a $U$ exists?)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! However, I don't have any idea about how to use the fact that $\pi$ is a covering map...

Comment: Things are at least a little easier than you're making them: everything in sight is linear, so to prove injectivity, you just need to show that if $\pi^*(a) = 0$, then $a = 0$.